# Shadow Sun Object data Propertie doesn't have softness setting

Tags: shadows

[image: )]

[image]
I am missing some of the settings and can't find them.
First one is mine.
Second is from the tutorial made in August 2019.
Did they move it somewhere else and how can I get to that?

Comment: I think it is now a global setting available in the render settings (where you choose between Cycles and Eevee) then Shadows > Soft Shadows

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! Can you just help me get to that settings. I knew where it was in blender 2.7 although I wasn't using it a lot.

Comment: I just added an answer so I could add a screenshot. Can you find it now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this setting has been changed to a global setting recently. You can find it in the render Settings, then the Shadows Subpanel, and the "Soft Shadows" checkbutton.

[image]

Comment: That's it! I couldn't find it and it will do! Thank you!